# How to call a Controler Action through inner g:each from GSP?

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a Domain class called **Student**.It contain some variables like **student_name,student_address,student_class**.Actually I want to display student details in order by **student_class**.

I have a GSP page called list.gsp.
**list.gsp :**

```
<g:each in="${std}" status="v" var="stdInstance"> //All Class eg:1..10.
<h3>${stdInstance.std_class}</h3>                   
 //Innerloop     
//here i want to display students details depending on the value of stdInstance.std_class.
</g:each>
```

I want to know how to call a controller action through inner g:each with passing params.

Comment: Is the variable std a 'list' of objects ?  And are you telling that you need to iterate through this list and depending on the value in each "stdInstance.std_class" you need to do something ?

Answer (score 1):

In my project I use the following to include a login section to my GSP pages where required:

```
<g:include controller="user" action="login"/>
```

Where controller is the controller name and action is the method in the controller. You can use the `params="..."` attribute in this tag to pass through parameters. I am sure you'll be able to do the same thing in your case. E.g.

```
<g:include controller="user" action="login" params="..."/>
```

Comment: Just make sure that the view exists. In this case it would expect "${PROJECT_DIR}/grails-app/views/user/login.gsp"

Comment: The params attribute should be formated as follows:
params="['arg1':'String to pass through']"

Answer (score 0):

I would rather sort the std list in the controller and pass the list already ordered. The only thing you would change is instead of passing list you would pass `list.sort{/*the order you want*/}`

If not, use the sort inside the g:each anyway... I guess it could be ambiguous though. Take a look at the [sort closure](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#sort%28groovy.lang.Closure%29).